# Count partial matches in Array using Application.Find or VBA.Filter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, find

I am trying to `Count` the number of `partial matches` in an 1D-Array without resorting to looping the array. `STerm` contains the string Key to search. I tried using the following functions:

`Sterm` is a `Dictionary` that i am looping and so changes everytime. The Dictionary items corresponding to that key is a 2D array of different string values. I am looping through the 1st dimension and it is a 1D array of values in which `Sterm` may be present.

e.g. if `Sterm` is `TC` then array may contain `TC`, `TC 1`, `TC A`... etc., and function should find and count these partial matches.

```
With Application
bCount = .Count(.Find(.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sTerm, 1))
bCount = .Count(.Find(.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sTerm & "*", 1))
...
```

Now the combination of `Application.Count` & `Application.Find` works well (as Count excludes any error values), but `Application.Find` results in an `EXACT` match. I want `PARTIAL` matches. `This looked very promising until it started returning 0 counts for partial matches i.e. it was not able to detect partial matches.`

> Also, there is no documentation available on MSDN or web for `Application.Find` Syntax.

Then i tried using `VBA.Filter` as it is known to return `Partial matches`. But `Application.Count`is not able to count `textual values`. So i used `Application.CountA`, but it results in a Type mismatch error for some unknown reason.

> Also i do not know what `VBA.Filter` returns if it is not to find any matches.

So i thought of doing a `VBA.Replace` of all partial matches to 1 and then feed it to `Count`. It is also resulting in error - `Expression not in expected context`.

```
Application.Count(CLng(VBA.Replace(Join(VBA.Filter(Application.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sterm, True, vbTextCompare), ","), sterm, 1)))
```

I tried using `Application.Countif` but not sure how to write it in VBA.

```
Application.CountIf(Application.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sterm & "*")
```

But it throws `Error 2015`.

Am i missing some syntax OR is there a better function to find and count partial matches without looping?

Comment: `Filter` returns elements that include (or exclude) the Match String so should consider partial matches. What code did you use?

Comment: @SJR, i have listed the filter code above. It returns partial matches, but results in Mismatch error if no matches found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `Filter` which I knocked up, without any errors. So it may come down to how you are declaring variables or similar.

```
Sub y()

Dim s(1 To 5) As String, v As Variant

s(1) = "Fred"      'includes "Fred"
s(2) = "Fred"      'includes "Fred"
s(3) = "Freddie"   'includes "Fred"
s(4) = "Harry"
s(5) = "Frederick" 'includes "Fred"

'v = Filter(s, "Fred", True) 'returns an array with 4 elements
'MsgBox UBound(v) + 1        'returns 4
'MsgBox Application.Index(Range("A1:A10"), UBound(v) + 1)

v = Filter(s, "Bill", True) 'returns an array with 0 elements (actually treated as -1)
MsgBox UBound(v) + 1        'returns 0

'to avoid error below
If UBound(v) > -1 Then
    MsgBox Application.Index(Range("A1:A10"), UBound(v) + 1)
Else
    MsgBox "Output array is empty"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: as you can see i am using the Filter function, and it returns partial matches. But donot know why it returns in `Type Mismatch` error sometimes. Is it because it may not find any partial matches?

Comment: You would probably need to check first the size of your output array as if you are not returning anything you cannot process the array. Probably boils down to adding an If statement.

Comment: Can you share an example? I tried with an IIF statement to return 0 on error, but still gave an error.

Comment: Yes I have added above. You might want to consider breaking down your operations into separate stages rather than doing it all in one line.

Comment: ^^^^ Can't second this recommendation enough.

Comment: @BigBen - am partly motivated by the fact that my creaky old brain can't get my head round lines like that above.

Comment: It's not a question of creakiness but readability and "debugability" :)

Comment: @SJR, should the IF condition line in above code be `If UBound(v) > 0 Then` or `If UBound(v) +1  > 0 Then` ?

Comment: thanks. But what do i use to get a count of the returned textual values?

Comment: As above, it would be `UBound(v) + 1` where `v` is the output array.

Comment: Ah! understood your approach now. Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: @SJR, finally got it working thanks to your alternative solution of `checking UBound of returned array` to get the `Count`. I still prefer short hand due to certain limitations i have in my code. Here is what i used:  `bCount = IIf(UBound(VBA.Filter(.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sTerm, True, vbTextCompare)) > -1, UBound(VBA.Filter(.Index(oVarDict(Key), i), sTerm)) + 1, 0)`

Comment: Glad it works. Each to his own, but the problem with that approach is, as BigBen says, that if it errors you won't know where it breaks